# Responsive divs needed with auto width

Tags: css, responsive-design

I try to have a row with 3 divs.
The middle div should be responsive with a mex-width, remaining space left and write should be filled in with a color.

I know I could solve this using an wrapper with auto-margin left and right but I need to have the center div transparent and not showing the wrapper background color.

I tried to solve this using a display table but did not manage to do this.

```
<div id="table">
    <div id="row">
        <div id="left"></div>
        <div id="middle">Row 1</div>
        <div id="right"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div id="row">
        <div id="left"></div>
        <div id="middle">Row 2</div>
        <div id="right"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

with css

```
#table {
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}
#row {
    width:100%;
    display:table-row;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
#left {
    width:auto;
    display:table-cell;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
#middle {
    display:table-cell;
    width:auto;
    max-width: 100px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
#right {
    width:auto;
    display:table-cell;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thepofo/kdJHh/2/

Ideas are welcome.

Comment: `id` attributes *must* be unique per document.

Comment: Changing ID to classes doesn't change must, still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The hacky way**

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/rFg2L/2/

```
.foo {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.foo > div {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100px;
}

.foo > div:before,
.foo > div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 999999px;
    background-color: red;
}

.foo > div:before {
    right: 100%;
}

.foo > div:after {
    left: 100%;
}
```

**The flexbox way** (http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/YYm32/

```
.foo { 
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;

    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;

    display: box;
    box-orient: horizontal;
}

.foo > div {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
}

.foo > div:nth-child(2) {
    max-width: 100px;
}

.foo > div:first-child,
.foo > div:last-child {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**Bonus track**

You don't need to add extra markup to clear your floats: http://jsfiddle.net/coma/Lqc2H/

Comment: Thanks, this solved it for me. and thank you for the clear floats tip

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be enough to work for you, but how about setting the div to 33% width of the wrapper.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="middle">Lorem ipsum dolor...</div>
    <div class="right">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

.wrap>div {
float:left;
    width: 33%;
}
.middle {
    max-width: 200px;
    outline:1px solid;
}
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gZsz5/)

Otherwise, you might want to consider media queries for specific widths.